# caching css and javascript

Tags: php, caching, etag

Im having trouble with caching...

Im using this php file with url rewriting to compress and cache css and js

I was under the impression that if i changed/updated one of my files, that the browser would retrieve the updated file. But it doesnt unless i clear the cache or refresh the page.

Is my coding wrong? Or is the browser not suppose to get updated content until the cache expiration period has expired?

```
<?php
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$_GET['file'];
$last_modified_time = filemtime($file);
$etag = md5_file($file);
$expires = 60*60*24*7;

if(file_exists($file))
{
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] != $etag)
    {   
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Cache-Control: maxage=$expires, must-revalidate");
        header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$expires) . ' GMT');
        header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", $last_modified_time)." GMT");
        header("Etag: \"{$etag}\"");

        if($_GET['type'] == 'js')  header('Content-type: application/javascript');
        if($_GET['type'] == 'css') header('Content-type: text/css');
        if($_GET['type'] == 'ico') header('Content-type: image/x-icon');

        ob_start("ob_gzhandler");       
        include($file);     
    }
    else {

        header('HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified');
    }
}
else {

    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
?>
```

rewrite rules

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).js$ /compress.php?file=$1.js&type=js [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*).css$ /compress.php?file=$1.css&type=css [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*).ico$ /compress.php?file=$1.ico&type=ico [L,QSA]
```

### ---------

**EDIT: Maybe i should be doing this a different way? what do the big companys use to cache, and how do they force browsers to get the updated content before the cache is set to expire?**

**EDIT 2: Thanks guy for the help. Im going with a 1 hour cache**

Answer (score 6):

The Browser doesn't refresh cached files until the given `Expires` header expired. If it's expired, it will request the file with an `If-None-Match` header (I guess).

But why didn't you handle cache control via `.htaccess`? You could check [`mod_expires`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html):

```
# Expires-Header
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 7 days"

# ETag
FileETag All
```

Gzip compression as well with [`mod_deflate`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html):

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/javascript
```

---

Edit: 'Big companies' don't use `Expires` or `max-age` headers, or they will set these headers to let cache files for ~1 hour -> conflicts with caching will be minimized. You're setting it to 1 week.

Comment: Im using II7 and a url rewrite from helicontech

Answer (score 1):

You missing these part, i believe...

```
    $last_modified = filemtime($file);

    // Check for cached version
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) OR isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'])) 
    {
        // these part should do that...
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] == gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $last_modified)) 
        {
            header('HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified');
            return;
        }
    }   
    header('Last-Modified : '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $last_modified));
    header('Cache-Control : max-age='.$expires.', must-revalidate');
    header('Expires : '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $last_modified + $expires));
    // and so on...
```

btw, for helping you determine, much more, related how your cache performance, or even better, your whole app performace, you can test it by using Google API performance, or these sites : http://www.webpagetest.org/ (PS: just for example, these is my latest result for my on working blog : http://www.webpagetest.org/result/110803_SB_17PVH/)

Comment: I think i already have that part, just done differently from how you did it

Comment: `if ($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] == gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $last_modified))` is the missing piece.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in theory the browser should pay attention to the `Cache-Control`, `Expires`, etc. information you're sending back, but in practice it's not always a good idea to trust the browser to do the right thing.

What you might want to consider doing is adding a second step in your compress.php script ... have it do a redirect to the actual compressed file, and append something like `"?ts=".$last_modified_time` to the path to the file. That way the URL will change when the file changes, and the browser will be much more likely to do the right thing and get the most recent file. I've used a similar technique before.

Comment: I dont really want to use redirects :/